# Unhandled Promise Rejection: IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmPayment(): elements should have a mounted Payment Element

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

My solution was working great until 1 week ago I got this message, and I see the log of the elements that comes empty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug in the recent update of react-stripe-js:

https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues/296